# Generating Matched Pairs for Statistical Analysis

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, hungarian-algorithm

In my study, a person is represented as a pair of real numbers (x, y). x is on [30, 80] and y is [60, 120]. There are two types of people, A and B. I have ~300 of each type. How can I generate the largest (or even a large) set of pairs of one person from A with one from B: ((xA, yA), (xB, yB)) such that each pair of points is close? Two points are close if abs(x1-x2) < dX and abs(y1 - y2) < dY. Similar constraints are acceptable. (That is, this constraint is roughly a Manhattan metric, but euclidean/etc is ok too.) Not all points need be used, but no point can be reused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hungarian_algorithm).

Suggested formulation: A are rows, B are columns, each cell contains a distance metric between Ai and Bi, e.g. abs(X(Ai)-X(Bi)) + abs(Y(Ai)-Y(Bi)). (You can normalize the X and Y values to [0,1] if you want distances to be proportional to the range of each variable)

Then use the Hungarian Algorithm to minimize matching weight.

You can filter out matches with distances over your threshold. If you're worried that this filtering might cause the approach to be sub-optimal, you could set distances over your threshold to a very high number.

There are many implementations of this algorithm. A short search found one in any conceivable language, including [VBA for Excel](http://www.thomashirsch.co.uk/2014/11/hungarian-algorithm-in-vbaexcel.html) and some [online solvers](http://www.hungarianalgorithm.com/solve.php) (not sure about matching 300x300 matrix with them, though)

Comment: Thanks so much, you're right! I used Python's munkres library and this tutorial: http://software.clapper.org/munkres/. The hardest part was finding a bug caused by using the matrix that is passed in with distances as a numpy array rather than a list. Must use lists! It ran in 3 minutes for two groups of each 250. The algorithm is O(n^3). Resulted in a ~20% improvement in number of pairs and gave better pairs, as compared to a naive algorithm I wrote.

Comment: Awesome! If this answered your question, you may want to accept the answer, or post your own, including your Python code and accept it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hungarian algorithm did it, thanks Etov.

Source code available here: http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflow1